# How can I iterate over combinations of all characters faster?

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, numba

I have a simple function that iterates over combinations of all characters using itertools.
I have calculated that for a 4 char string it takes 94secs. But for 7 it already takes ~3600hours or 157 days. 
I have tried using numba's jit with and without cuda and it didn't work since itertools isn't compatible with numba.
I also tried Threading but that didn't work.
I did this:

```
def test(j):
    pass

def start():
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(2, 3):
        for j in map(''.join, itertools.product(myLetters, repeat = i)):
            t = Thread(target = test, args = j)
            t.start()
```

But it just spammed me with "Exception in ThreadN Exeption in ThreadN etc.
Can someone help me make this code run faster?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using `list(itertools.permutations([0, 1, 2, 3]))` and using the resulting all permutations as indeces for the characters in your string?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  One thread per permutation of characters seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I am just beginning to take on scripting, and I wanted some kind of brute-forcer for Passwords or something like that. So something that generates all possible combinations of characters with increasing length until I stop it. And I got the idea to do this from this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyJfLUYQA5w

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a huge problem space.  Even if you only use uppercase letters + lowercase letters + numbers, you are looking at 62^<length> permutations.  (e.g. 7 characters => 62^7 = 3,521,614,606,208 permutations.)  So at the very least you need to 1) make sure you are doing as little work per permutation as possible (e.g. don't spin up new threads!), and 2) make sure you are streaming the results and that you never try to hold them all in memory at once.

Comment: @IfClause you need to mention in your original question that you are hashing the strings to crack a password. It takes ~3600hours to brute force a 7 char string because the hashing function takes a relatively long time to complete, and it is called (7^7) 823543 times. Generating those 823543 strings one at a time with `itertools.product()` happens extremely quickly. It is not the bottleneck. So you're asking the wrong question ("How can I iterate over combinations of all characters faster?").

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do? This code rearranges the characters of a string to all permutations. For 7 characters it's basically instantaneous.

```
import itertools

word = '1234567'
word = list(word)

# Create all permutation of numbers that will be the indeces of the characters
all_permutations = list(itertools.permutations(range(len(word))))

# For each permutation create a string that has each of its characters repositioned to new index
for permutation in all_permutations:
    new_word = ''.join([word[i] for i in permutation])
    print(f'new_word = {new_word}')
```

Comment: Thank you, this is amazing!

Comment: So sadly I've come to the conclusion that for my usecase that isn't faster. Because with each combination i hash it and compare the hashes to a given hash. That is apparently what takes so long. So your solution is way more elegant but not faster for my usecase sadly. Thanks anyway

Comment: I'm sorry to hear! I'll give it another thought later. Are you running into a nested loop with this one too?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the combinations (colloquially) without storing them in memory at once:

```py
import itertools

def get_next_combination(iterable):
    for i in range(1, len(iterable)+1):
        yield from map("".join, itertools.product(iterable, repeat=i))


for combination in get_next_combination("abc"):
    print(combination)
    # if hash_algorithm(combination) == known_hash: print("Password found!")
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
aa
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc
aaa
aab
aac
aba
abb
abc
aca
acb
acc
baa
bab
bac
bba
bbb
bbc
bca
bcb
bcc
caa
cab
cac
cba
cbb
cbc
cca
ccb
ccc
```

It can handle 7 character strings in ~3 seconds, no worries.

If you're actually trying to crack a password, I would suggest just using hashcat, or at least carry out a dictionary attack with a huge list of known passwords.

Using multiple threads might not actually speed things up because [the reference implementation of] Python will only execute one Python bytecode at a time. Though I believe itertools is written in C, so it probably releases the GIL. Nevertheless, you normally need to utilise `multiprocessing` to improve CPU-bound Python programs.